# show image with row value using if statement in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to show an specific image when a row value returns from the db

For example:
When a value returns as 1 i want to show [image: fire]

But i know only the php code in codeigniter i get the error tn7

controller:

```
public function ajax_list()
{


    $list = $this->person->get_datatables_vandaag();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $person) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();

        $current = $row[] = $person->doel;
            if($current=='3') {echo 'image' ;} 
            elseif($current=='4') {echo 'image' ;} 
            elseif($current=='2') {echo 'image' ;} 
            elseif($current=='1') {echo 'image' ;}
        $row[] = $person->firm;
        $row[] = $person->name;
        $row[] = $person->phone;
        }
```

view:

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
                <th style="width:100px;">Firm</th>
                <th style="width:100px;">Name</th>
                <th style="width:75px;">number</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>


    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to add the images in the view,

In controller

```
$list = $this->person->get_datatables_vandaag();
$this->load->view('your-view.php',$list);
```

your-view.php file

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
                <th style="width:100px;">Firm</th>
                <th style="width:100px;">Name</th>
                <th style="width:75px;">number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
foreach ($list as $key => $person) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
if($key=='3')
{echo 'image' ;} 
elseif($key=='4') {echo 'image' ;} 
elseif($key=='2') {echo 'image' ;} 
elseif($key=='1') {echo 'image' ;}
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>'.$person->firm.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$person->name.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$person->number.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
</tbody>
</table>
```